# Nginx redirect rule has no affect

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

Trying to do a simple redirect:

```
rewrite https://url.example.com(.*) https://example.com/plugins/url permanent;
```

Anytime `url.example.com` is hit, I want it to redirect to that specific path.

**EDIT:**

Will try to explain this better, as I'm trying to redirect to a specific domain from another.

```
server {
    server_name example.com plugin.example.com;
    root /home/www/example.com/public;
}
```

I see the `location` used for redirects such as:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

But not sure how to use it in my case, which is to change `plugin.example.com` to `example.com/plugin`.

For example:

```
http://plugin.example.com
https://plugin.example.com
https://plugin.example.com/blah
https://plugin.example.com/blah/more
```

All of these should redirect to:

```
https://example.com/plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Redirect from subdomain to subfolder on main site

Do you require a redirect from a subdomain to a subfolder on the main site?

- This would be best accomplished by a separate `server` context, with the appropriate [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/r/server_name) specification.
- Else, you could also do this with an [`if`](http://nginx.org/r/if) statement testing against [`$host`](http://nginx.org/r/$host).
- As already pointed out elsewhere, [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) directive operates based on [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/r/$uri), which does not contain the hostname.

---

### `server_name`-based matching (recommended):

#### Hardcoded redirect with a limited number of hostnames (recommended):

```
server {
    server_name     plugin.example.com;
    return  301     $scheme://example.com/plugin$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name     about.example.com;
    return  301     $scheme://example.com/about$request_uri;
}
```

---

#### Regex-based redirect from any subdomain to the main domain:

```
server {
    server_name     ~^(?:www\.)?(?<subdomain>.*)\.example\.com$;
    return  301     $scheme://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

---

#### Regex-based redirect from a limited number of subdomain to the main domain:

```
server {
    server_name     ~^(?:www\.)?(?<subdomain>plugin|about)\.example\.com$;
    return  301     $scheme://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

---

---

### `if`-based:

#### If-statement-based redirect with hardcoded hostnames:

```
server {
    server_name     .example.com;
    …
    if ($host = plugin.example.com) {
        return  301     $scheme://example.com/plugin$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = about.example.com) {
        return  301     $scheme://example.com/about$request_uri;
    }
    …
}
```

---

#### If-statement-based redirect with a regex-based matching:

```
server {
    server_name     .example.com;
    …
    if ($host ~ ^(?:www\.)?(?<subdomain>plugin|about)\.example\.com$) {
        return  301     $scheme://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
    }
    …
}
```

---

Please refer to http://nginx.org/r/server_name for more discussion of which option may be best for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the original URL is `https://url.example.com` or `https://url.example.com/` then the normalized URI used by the `rewrite` and `location` directives will be `/`. The scheme, host name and query string have all been removed.

To perform a permanent redirect to a URL with a different host name:

Using `rewrite` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details):

```
rewrite ^/$ https://example.com/foo permanent;
```

Or using `location` and `return` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details):

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://example.com/foo;
}
```

The second solution is more efficient, as there are no *regular expressions* to process.

If the original URL includes a query string: The `rewrite` will append it automatically unless a trailing `?` is added. The `return` will not, but can be added by appending `$is_args$args`.

---

If the scheme and host name are unchanged, then both statements can be simplified:

```
rewrite ^/$ /foo permanent;
```

Or:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate servers for example.com and plugin.example.com. And create redirect inside plugin.example.com server.

```
server {
    server_name plugin.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/plugin;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/www/example.com/public;
}
```